# Mouse sensitivity is not changing when slider value is changed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set the mouse sensitivity, but "Int Sensitivity" is not updating when the slider value is changed. I can't seem to find a fix for my problem but if you know what dumb mistake, I made please let me know. thxs :)

```
public int Sensitivity;

public Slider SensitivitySlider;

public void SetSensitivity()
{
    SensitivitySlider.value = Sensitivity;
}

private void Update()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("sensitivity", Sensitivity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something to listen to your Slider value changes.

In order to combine the loading of existing value as well you should do e.g.

```
public class IntSliderController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Encapsulation!
    [SerializeField] private string key = "sensitivity";
    [SerializeField] private Slider slider;
    [SerializeField] private int defaultValue;

    private int _currentValue;

    // public read only access
    public int CurrentValue => _currentValue;
    // Event forwarding changes on the slider but also 
    // called on start after loading existing playerprefs value
    public event Action<int> ValueChanged;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // As fallback if not assigned via inspector search Slider component on this object
        if(!slider) slider = GetComponent<Slider>();

        // attach a listener to be called whenever the value 
        // of the slider is changed by the user
        slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(HandleSliderValueChanged);
    }

    private void Start ()
    {
        // Load existing playerprefs value using defaultValue as fallback
        _currentValue = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key, defaultValue);
        // Also apply value to the slider 
        slider.value = _currentValue;
    }

    private void HandleSliderValueChanged()
    {
        _currentValue = slider.value;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(key, _currentValue);
        ValueChanged?.Invoke(_currentValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The slider doesn't know anything about your variable.
You need to handle the change yourself.

Add a function:

```
public void OnSliderValueChanged(int newValue)
{
    Sensitivity = newValue;
}
```

Then, in the inspector for the slider, link the value changed UnityEvent to the OnSliderValueChanged function in your script (make sure to use the option in the top of the list with the dynamic parameter, or it will always pass a constant).

The slider will call the event when its value changes, which will then call your function, which will then update the Sensitivity variable.

Comment: There is no option to set it as a dynamic parameter. I can only set it as a constant.

Comment: Oh, I see your problem now.  Yeah, that's how C# works.  Numeric values are not reference types.  You can't assign it a reference that stays linked.  You have to set/get it when it changes and manage that yourself.

Answer (score -1):

If you intend to make a slider in Unity, just use the `Range` attribute.

```cs
[Range(0, 1)]
public float sensitivity;
```

Also, if you want it to be applied directly in the editor, use `OnValidate()` event.

```cs
public void OnValidate()
{
    Debug.Log(sensitivity); // show value on change
}
```

Comment: I doubt that OP was looking for a slider in the Inspector but rather a Slider UI visible to the user of the app

Comment: Anyway, there is no problem if one slider is in the Unity inspector and the other is in the game view. @derHugo

Comment: No it's not a problem at all .. but doesn't address OPs issue in any way .. of course you are always free to add some visual fanciness to the Inspector .. it still won't affect the not working UI Slider OP is using in any way though...

Comment: @derHugo In fact, the OP has not mentioned anywhere that the problem is the slider in the game or the slider on the inspector. Anyway, since your answer covers the part you raised, I'll move on to the other part.